# Arduino Due C Timer Coding (Interrupt Counting)

Tags: c, timer, count, arduino, sleep

I have an Arduino Due that I'm doing a lot of really neat stuff with in one section of code I'm handeling a flowsensor and getting readings from it. the flowsensor is hooked up to an interrupt as it is a hallsensor device. The problem I'm having is that my math is based off of a single seconds worth of collection data, when I turn on the interrupt and sleep for a second do the calculations for flowrate in gp/m it works great. For My purposes however I can't afford to pause and collect data, so instead I calculate a change in time of greater than a thousand milliseconds. then I take the amount of time passed since the last loop, devide it by 1000 milliseconds or 1 second then I have the percentage of 1 second stored in a variable, I multiply the count by the percentage and should arrive at the number of counts per second. This however results in an ever growing number regardless of the fact that I zero the numbers prior to the next loop. Below I've included the way I formatted the expressions and the loop code for the flowsensor, I'd post the whole code but I don't want to waste space on stackoverflow and I know that portion of code already works with the sleep method.

```
long currentMillis = 0;
long lastMillis = 0;
int checkMillis = 0;
volatile int NbTopsFan; //measuring the rising edges of the signal
int newNbTopsFan;
float realNbTopsFan;
float realMillis;
float Calc;
float Calcd;
int Calcf;
int hallsensor = 7;

void loop()
{
  if (lastMillis = 0) {
    lastMillis = millis();
  }
  currentMillis = millis();
  checkMillis = (currentMillis - lastMillis);
  if (checkMillis >= 1000) {
    realMillis = (checkMillis / 1000);
    realNbTopsFan = (NbTopsFan * realMillis);
    newNbTopsFan = realNbTopsFan;
    Calc = (newNbTopsFan * 60 / 7.5); //(Pulse frequency x 60) / 7.5Q, = flow rate
    Calc = (Calc / 60);
    Calc = (Calc / 3.78541);
    Calc = (Calc * 1.47);
    Calcd = (Calc * 100);
    Calcf = Calcd;
    NbTopsFan = 0;
    lastMillis = 0;
    checkMillis = 0;
    realMillis = 0;
    realNbTopsFan = 0;
    newNbTopsFan = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: this line: realMillis = (checkMillis / 1000); will fail to give correct answer because it is performing an integer divide.  A better aproach would be seconds = checkMillis /1000; realMillis = (checkmillis - seconds); or something similar, depending on exactly what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line should read:

```
if ( lastMillis == 0 ) {
    lastMillis = millis();
}
```

You need the double = to evaluate the variable